# Is there some general limit on temperature of electric arc?

Tags: temperature, plasma-physics, lightning

You can find that [max. temperature of electric arc is ~20 000](https://www.quora.com/How-much-heat-does-an-electrical-arc-produce) K (e.g. in lightning), but why?
I assume temperature of electric arc is given by balance between input power (current denisty and voltage) and losses (mostly radiation, I guess). So if you have enough power you should achieve any temperature you want?

But I heard recently that there should be some hard limit - that if you e.g. increase voltage and power the arc simply expands and temperature does not increase further. Still I assume this would very much depend on the environment (e.g. pressure atomic composition of plasma)

- Is it true?
- Are there any simple fundamental mechanisms and formulas
  behind that?

Comment: Why do you think lightning is limited to 20,000 K?  If there is an upper limit on lightning, it's most likely due to the breakdown voltage of air.  That is, you cannot build up an arbitrarily large charge in Earth's atmosphere as eventually the electric field will be large enough to break the insulator-like barrier of the air.

Comment: I don't know if there is such limit. It is the question whether there is such limit. I just heart it, therefore I ask.

Answer (score 1):

According to the *Stefan-Boltzmann Law*, the total radiative power across the electromagnetic spectrum emitted by a hot object varies according to the *fourth* power of the absolute temperature. This means as an object gets really hot, its heat loss by radiation gets really, really, really big, and it gets really, really, really hard to push its temperature up further.

This means that if you try pumping more and more power into (for example) an electric arc to get it hotter and hotter, there will come a point at which the power required to get it even one degree kelvin hotter is so huge that its temperature limits out, and that's all you get.

To get truly huge temperatures requires an energy source of incredible power to keep up with the radiative losses, which is why only atomic and hydrogen bombs can get as hot as they do.

Comment: yes. This is starting point for me (the input-output power balance). But I wonder if there is other limiting mechanism which hits you first.

Comment: Consider e.g. [Z-machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_Pulsed_Power_Facility) as power-source. Normally they use it to compress some gas by implosion achieving billions K. I wonder if they simply use it to discharge as normal eletric arc, if you can get way beyond 20000K.

Comment: You can get 100M Kelvin with lasers too, but the temperature vanishes in a few nanoseconds